# How can I increase the waiting time for CompletionItemProvider for my VSCode Extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Currently I have coded out a VSCode extension which makes calls to a backend API and the generated content will appear as inline suggestions through the usage of InlineCompletionItemProvider. However, the backend API will take about 40s to 1 min to generate the content, and the content does not appear as inline suggestions when returned from the API. I was thinking this is because the InlineCompletionItemProvider has a waiting time limit for the response, and hence I would like to check if this time limit can be raised. I have been searching around but I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere. Thank you!